# A grid with items having fixed width and height

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, flexbox, css-grid

Currently I create a 10x10 grid with these settings:

```js
/*
This code is easier than writing many lines of HTML code
*/

$(document).ready(() => {
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    const parent = $("<div></div>");
    parent.addClass("p");
    for (let j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
      const child = $("<div></div>");
      child.addClass("c");
      parent.append(child);
    }
    $("#page").append(parent);
  }
});
```

```css
.p {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 1px;
}

.c {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-left: 1px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="page"></div>
```

The cells have a fixed height and width. This grid might be bigger than the screen width but this doesn't matter.

I want all cells per row getting placed next to each other I tried two ways:

Using `display: flex` I get the result above. But when changing the screen width, the cells get stretched.

Using `display: inline-block` I get this result:

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    const parent = $("<div></div>");
    parent.addClass("p");
    for (let j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
      const child = $("<div></div>");
      child.addClass("c");
      parent.append(child);
    }
    $("#page").append(parent);
  }
});
```

```css
.p {
  margin-top: 1px;
}

.c {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 1px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="page"></div>
```

Now I get a weird bottom spacing on each row.

How can I create a grid that keeps its width and height with a spacing of 1px per cell?

Comment: Isn't your first snippet doing the trick? What do you exactly want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Flexbox

In your flex version you say:

> The cells have a fixed height and width.

No they don't. The width is not fixed.

An initial setting of a flex container is [**`flex-shrink: 1`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-shrink). This means that flex items can *shrink* from their initial size in order to remain inside their container.

The property applies along the main axis, which means that in a row-direction container, `flex-shrink` affects width.

Here's your code, with `flex-shrink` disabled:

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    const parent = $("<div></div>");
    parent.addClass("p");
    for (let j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
      const child = $("<div></div>");
      child.addClass("c");
      parent.append(child);
    }
    $("#page").append(parent);
  }
});
```

```css
.p {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 1px;
}

.c {
  flex-shrink: 0; /* new */
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-left: 1px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="page"></div>
```

[**jsFiddle demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/36zx1rt4/)

---

### Grid

For an even simpler solution use CSS Grid Layout.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    $("#container").append("<div style='background-color:red'></div>");
});
```

```css
#container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(10, 30px);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(10, 30px);  
  grid-gap: 1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

[**jsFiddle demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/36zx1rt4/1/)

Comment: Added a second (and simpler) solution.

Answer (score 0):

try adding this to your second example

```
.p {
    font-size:0;
}
```

display `inline` elements have underlying margins depending on their font-size

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
#page {
    font-size: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to create grid with the style you want is to use `table` instead of set of `div`s and set `min-width` property for `td`s.

```js
const createGrid = (rows, columns) => {
  const table = document.createElement('table');
  document.body.appendChild(table);

  for (let i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    let row = document.createElement('tr');
    table.appendChild(row);

    for (let j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
      let cell = document.createElement('td');
      row.appendChild(cell);
    }
  }
}

createGrid(10, 10);
```

```css
table {
  border-spacing: 1px;
}
td {
  min-width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: red;
}
```